# Spaces of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $p_{1}(x)=-2x+2$, $p_{2}(x)=x+2$, $p_{3}(x)=x^{2}+2x+3$, $p_{4}(x)=x^{2}-x+3$.
>
> a) From the above four polynomials, determine a linearly independent subset that spans the polynomials.
>
> b) What is the dimension of the (sub)space that this basis spans?
>
> c) Does this basis span the space of the second degree polynomials? If not, describe the  subspace it spans in terms of the coefficients of a polynomial that belongs to this subspace?

I said since the Wronskian is 0, the functions are linearly dependent. We see three non-zero rows there. This means three of the functions form a linearly independent set of functions. So, {$p_{1}(x),p_{2}(x),p_{3}(x)$} is subset that spans the space of second degree polynomials and is a basis for this space. The dimension is three since there are three functions that form the basis. But parts a and c yelling at me: "Wrong!". Can somebody help me?

Comment: You determined that the 4 are linearly dependent.  Then you listed 3 and proposed they are a basis.  You still need to show these 3 are independent.  (They are.)  THEN you conclude the dimension is 3.

Answer (score 1):

(a) Let $\vec p_i$ be the coefficient vector of $p_i(x)$. Then, 
$$M= 
\begin{bmatrix}
 \vec p_1 & \vec p_2 & \vec p_3 & \vec p_4
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
-2 & 1 & 2 & -1 \\
2 & 2 & 3 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
.$$

Columns $1$, $2,$ and $3$ are pivot columns $\Rightarrow T =\{p_1, p_2, p_3 \}$ is a linearly independent subset that spans $\{p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4 \} \Rightarrow T$ forms a basis for $\operatorname{Span} \{p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4 \}$.

(b) $\dim (\operatorname{Span} T) = \operatorname{Rank} M = 3.$

(c) Let $p \in \mathbb{P}^2$. Then, $p$ is of the form $ax^2+bx+c$. The corresponding system to solve is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec p_1 & \vec p_2 & \vec p_3 & \vec p
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & a \\
-2 & 1 & 2 & b \\
2 & 2 & 3 & c
\end{bmatrix}
\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} a + \frac{1}{6}c - \frac{1}{3} b \\
0 & 1 & 0 & - \frac{5}{3} a + \frac{1}{3}c + \frac{1}{3} b  \\
0 & 0 & 1 & a
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

We can see that the system is consistent, and $$p = \left( \frac{1}{6} a + \frac{1}{6}c - \frac{1}{3} b \right)p_1 +
\left( -\frac{5}{3} a + \frac{1}{3}c + \frac{1}{3} b \right) p_2 + a p_3. $$
Hence, $\operatorname{Span} T = \mathbb{P}^2$. But, we showed that $T$ was linearly independent $\Rightarrow T$ forms a basis for $\mathbb{P}^2$.