# Let $(P_3)_E$ denote the space $P_3$ with the standard basis $E = \{1, x, x^2\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(P_3)_E$ denote the space $P_3$ with the standard basis $E = \{1, x, x^2\}$.

1)  If $p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2$ is a polynomial in $P_3$, what column vector represents $p(x)$ with respect to the standard basis, $E$?

- So here, I have that the column vector is (a_1, a_1, a_2)...?

2)  Define vectors $u_1(x) := 1 + x + x^2$, $u_2(x) := 1 + 2x$, $u_3(x) := 1 + 2x + x^2$ in $P_3$. Show that $F = \{u_1, u_2, u_3\}$ is a basis of $P_3$.

- Here, I have that $1+x+x^2$ = ($a_1+a_2+a_3$) + x($a_1+a_2+a_3$) + $x^2$($a_1+a_2$), but I'm not sure what to do next.

3)  What column vector represents the polynomial $p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2$ with respect to $F = \{u_1, u_2, u_3\}$?

4)  Find the transition matrix from $(P_3)_E$ to $(P_3)_F$.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Are you, for instance, comfortable with the same kind of questions (checking that a set of vectors is a basis, changing basis etc.) for more conventional vector spaces, such as $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: @Arthur I am struggling to find a starting place

Comment: One place to start is that the answer to 1) is $(a_0,a_1,a_2)^T$. Can you see how this vector is connected to your polynomial?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.

Comment: For (2), you can look at the following questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173044/show-that-p-1-p-2-p-3-is-a-basis?rq=1 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081024/spaces-of-polynomials?rq=1