# Consider $E:= \{1, 1+x, 1+x+x^2\}$ as a basis of $P_3$. Find the matrix representations of $D$ as an operator from $(P_3)_E$ to $(P_3)_E$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $E:=\{1, 1+x, 1+x+x^2\}$ as a basis of $P_3$. Find the matrix representations of $D$ as an operator from $(P_3)_E$ to $(P_3)_E$.
I have an answer but I don't think that it is correct. $D:= f '(x)-f(x)$

I got 
$$
D = \pmatrix{
-1 & 0 & 0\\
0  & 1 & 1\\
0  & 0 & -1}
$$

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194095/let-p-3-e-denote-the-space-p-3-with-the-standard-basis-e-1-x-x2?rq=1). Why is your answer not correct ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde this seems to be a different (but related) question

Comment: @TylerBonts could you please tell us what you got for your answer?

Comment: @TylerBonts Is this question part of a series? Did you previously calculate $D$ with respect to a different basis?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I edited my question with what i got for the D matrix. also added what D is.

Answer (score 0):

Let $v_1 = 1, v_2 = 1+x, v_3 = 1+x+x^2$.  We have
$$
Dv_1 = -v_1\\
Dv_2 = -v_2\\
Dv_3 = v_2 - v_3
$$
So, you have the right matrix.